# Simple MySQL WHILE loop not running

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a while loop from a MySQL query (which I've done a ton of times) and I can't get it to run for some reason. If I run the code below, I get 'test' echoed out but not 'test2' even though there are entries in the database that match the criteria in my SQL query. I guess I'm just trying to see if I'm overlooking something in the syntax?

I have the database connect files included on the page with 'require' statements so the page wouldn't even run if it was a mistake when connecting to the database.

Any ideas? I'm sorry if this is basic, it's just been driving me crazy
 this morning. Thank you for your help!

```
$sql_all = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status != 'trash' AND post_status != 'auto-draft'";
$result_all = $mysqli->query($sql_all);

echo "test";

while($row_all == mysqli_fetch_array($result_all)){
    echo "test2";    
}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors?  What do you see if you do `echo $mysqli->error;`?  Maybe the query returns 0 rows?  What do you see if you do `echo $result_all->num_rows`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take out the second equal sign in your while loop.

```
while($row_all = mysqli_fetch_array($result_all)){
```

Comment: Yes, as strange is it may look, this is correct.  You are assigning the value returned by `mysqli_fetch_array`, then checking if it's "truthy".

Comment: Really?  Wow, I learn something new every day!  Thanks for the tip, Rocket.

Comment: I was just expanding on your answer ;)

Comment: Had it been a "conditional statement", then it would be a different story. Since it's a `while` (loop), then the single `=` sign must be applied as "equaling to" and not "assigned to".